# Centering background of centered menu to page

Tags: css

I am having some confusion sorting out how to gain 100%  centering elements.

I am trying to have a grey background with a slightly larger width than the centered horizontal menu.I want the grey background to reach the very top of the page to the bottom of the page. While testing the code  it will change the way the menu is aligned and not center the menu to both the screen/page and background.

**I have edited code to give better visualization of issues (4th edit)**

```css
html {
  background-color: rgba(255, 216, 0, 0.4);
}
a {
  float: left;
  width: 8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #0094ff;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #b6ff00;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
div {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.table {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
#horizontal-list {
  background-color: #808080;
  padding: 5em;
  height: auto;
  width: 75%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Sitestyles.css">
  <title>blahblah</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="menubg">
        <ul id="horizontal-list">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code in order to avoid the gap in the top margin:

```
body {

margin:0;
padding:0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, what about the grey background behind the menu? How can I make it extend to the bottom and center without using pixels?

Answer (score 0):

maybe so ?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
}

html {
    background-color: rgba(255, 216, 0, 0.4);
}

div {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.table {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.menubg {}
.menubg > ul {
    text-align: center;    
    background-color: #808080;
    padding: 5em;    
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;    
}
.menubg > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.menubg > ul > li a {
    display: block;
    width: 8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0094ff;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.menubg > ul > li a:hover {
    background-color: #b6ff00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="menubg">
            <ul id="horizontal-list">
                <li> <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a></li><li> <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a></li><li> <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a></li><li> <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a></li><li> <a href="#">
              <img src="image.png" onmousedown="return false;" alt="Something" />
            </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```